# Adding values from the sqlite3 callback function to wxGrid

Tags: c++, sqlite, wxwidgets

I have a table of students like this (~60 students in table)

| ID  | FULL_NAME |

| 1   | Tony      |

| 2   | Max       |

Then i'm passing a pointer to a wxGrid object as second argument of GetStudents function.

```
int cDatabase::GetStudents(wxString path_to_db, wxGrid* grid)
{
    sqlite3* db;

    char* zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    std::string sql;

    rc = sqlite3_open(path_to_db, &db);

    if (rc) {
        wxLogMessage(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    sql = "SELECT FULL_NAME FROM 'STUDENTS'; ";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, grid, &zErrMsg);

    if (rc) {
        wxLogMessage(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in callback i'm creating a grid (on a pointer to wxGrid object) with the number of rows equal to argc received from a callback function

```
int cDatabase::callback(void* c_data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    wxGrid* grid = reinterpret_cast<wxGrid*>(c_data);

    grid->CreateGrid(argc, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

But at the very end argc equals to 1. Also if i will go trough the argv,

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    grid->SetCellValue(i, 1, wxString::FromUTF8(argv[i]));
}
```

this will cause an access violation error.
Also, must to note that if i use Append function with wxComboBox object

```
cb_group->Append(wxString::FromUTF8(*argv));
```

this will work without any problems, it just fills the combobox with received from callback values.

How can i easily iterate trough the argv without errors?
Any solutions please, I'm really tired of this.

Comment: can you post complete callback function? Also, I believe that the callback is called for every row that is retrieved from the SQLite, not at the end of the sqlite3_exec. So you need to rethink the design of the application.

Comment: From SQLite documentation: `If the callback function of the 3rd argument to sqlite3_exec() is not NULL, then it is invoked for each result row coming out of the evaluated SQL statements.`. So the actual row count is correct - it is `1`.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the argument for `sqlite3_open` should be `path_to_db.utf8_str()`, because sqlite always takes the filename in UTF-8, regardless of platform.

Comment: @Igor oh, I have not read about it in the documentation, now i got it. Thanks!

Comment: @LauriNurmi it is already in utf-8

Comment: @IXP No it isn't, not portably. A `wxString` that is implitly cast to `char*` (as is the case here), doesn't return UTF-8 on Windows.